# XLET - how to create a simple xlet MHP javax.TV

Tags: netbeans, java-me, xlet

I'm trying to create my first xlet project.
Can you help me?

I don't know which library I need to download.
What kind of project I have to create? (I'm using netbeans)

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions, where you demonstrate your problem, what did not work and what you tried. It is not an online tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This site has a lot of useful info:
http://www.interactivetvweb.org/tutorials/javatv/first_xlet

You can use XletView to view your Xlet.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xletview/

You will need to get a hold on the various API's, which is somewhat troublesome (I've heard).
But there are also other ways of getting them. For example, if you own PowerDVD, you'll be able to find BDJ.jar somewhere in that package. Add that to your classpath, and you'll be able to compile your Xlet.

If you're running Windows, you can probably develop Xlets with JavaME SDK 3.0 too (sadly not available for Linux though).